# embed link in php mail function

Tags: php, html, html-email

Im trying to embed an

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

for example. In the email however it shows all the html code. I think this might be for security reasons to avoid phising scams such as getting people to visit links they do not intend to. This is the best method i can think of as I am passing sensitive informations and just want the user to see the link as just the word 'Google'.

Note: google is being used here as an example only.

Comment: I think you may be missing this : Content-Type: text/HTML;

Comment: Don't use PHP's `mail()` function. Use a decent mailer class like phpMailer or Switfmailer. These make it easy to send properly formatted HTML emails. The built-in `mail()` function is really bad at stuff like that, where you need to define custom headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Example #4 in the [PHP documentation for `mail`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

In particular, this part:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the correct headers?
Straight from php.net

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

See more, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), Example #4 about sending html email.